# Extraer el valor de un Item de un DropDownList que se llena con un query de sql server C# y aspx

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un DropDownList llamado **Venta** que lleno de la siguiente manera:

```
 DataRow fila = dtr.Rows[0];
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT A.CardCode, A.CardName, B.SlpName FROM OCRD A INNER JOIN OSLP B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode ='" + Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]) + "' AND LicTradNum = 'XAXX010101000'", cn);
 OdbcDataAdapter daa = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable ds = new DataTable();
 daa.Fill(ds);
 VENTA.DataSource = ds;     
 VENTA.DataTextField = "CardName";
 VENTA.DataValueField = "CardCode";
 VENTA.DataBind();
```

Le asigno como **valor** a cada Item el **CardCode** correspondiente. Mi intención es mostrar **CardCode** en un Label, dependiendo del Item que se seleccionó y ésto por medio del evento Click de un Botón.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado hacer? ?Tienes ejemplos? Trata de colocar todo el código que depende para lograr tu resultado, así te podremos ayudar de mejor forma.

Comment: Solamente con `Label1.Text = DropDownList.SelectedValue;` pero me marca error: `ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ' Oaxaca 3K'. ` Osea que está tomando el nombre, más no su valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar parametros en lugar de concatenar tu query

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT A.CardCode, A.CardName, B.SlpName  FROM OCRD A INNER JOIN OSLP B ON A.SlpCode = B.SlpCode WHERE B.SlpCode =@slpcode AND LicTradNum = 'XAXX010101000'", cn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slpcode",Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]);
```

Por que tu error esta en la consulta, tambien puedes intentar hacer la misma consulta en sql server para ver si funciona